# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot'

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using Webpack 4 and installed "`font-awesome": "^4.7.0"` in `package.json`. Then I tried to import it into my `index.scss` as following:

```
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

And I've got the following error message:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/index.scss)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot' in '/Volumes/Develop/react-reason/cockpit/src'
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/index.scss 7:414-457

    ERROR in ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/index.scss)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0' in '/Volumes/Develop/react-reason/cockpit/src'
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/index.scss 7:332-383

    ERROR in ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/index.scss)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0' in '/Volumes/Develop/react-reason/cockpit/src'
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/index.scss 7:806-857

    ERROR in ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/index.scss)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0' in '/Volumes/Develop/react-reason/cockpit/src'
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/index.scss 7:711-762

    ERROR in ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/index.scss)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0' in '/Volumes/Develop/react-reason/cockpit/src'
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/index.scss 7:525-578

    ERROR in ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/index.scss)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0' in '/Volumes/Develop/react-reason/cockpit/src'
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/index.scss 7:619-671
```

As you can see, **bootstrap** works fine, but **font-awesome** not.
The folder of downloaded font-awesome looks as following:
[image]

Do I miss some configuration?

**Update**
Import the css file like:

```
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

but import scss file like:

```
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
```

does not work why?

Comment: `FontAwesome` work too, it just missed web fonts, Open font awesome `scss` file and try to update your path, like this: `'~font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot'` and also for others. Or `'./font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot'`

Comment: `font-awesome` is intalled via `npm i`, everytime when I would delete `node_modules` package, I have to adjust it?

Comment: Only thing that works for me is `@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';`. I used `create-react-app` to create the base for the app, so I don't manage any loaders myself.

Answer (score 38):

Specify the font location before import :

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts/";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

Answer (score 4):

I made it work with these steps:

create `src/_variables.scss` with content:

```
$fa-font-path: '../node_modules/font-awesome-sass/assets/fonts/font-awesome/';
```

So I set the complete path beginning `../node_modules`

and for completeness my `src/styles.scss`:

```
@import 'variables';
@import "../node_modules/font-awesome-sass/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome";
```

(I'm using package `font-awesome-sass` so your path(s) may differ)

Answer (score 2):

change it

```
$fa-font-path: "./webfonts";
```

for exemple (fontawesome 5):

```
$fa-font-path: "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";
```

in app.scss

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to import it without the trailing .scss or .css. So try the following

```
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome';
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```